# kohana hide action name in url for particular action

Tags: action, kohana, routes

I have default route like this:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>(/<id2>))))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'directory' => 'frontend'
    ));
```

I also have articles controller with action add and action show.

What i need is hide show (action name) in url but keep add (action name) in url.

I have tried to add another route:

```
Route::set('article_show', 'article(/<id>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'frontend',
        'controller' => 'article',
        'action' => 'show',
    ));
```

But then only show action is working for all urls.
I need article/id url working and article/add working but article/show/id should not be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Route::set('article_show', 'article((/<action>)/<id>)', array('action' => 'add', 'id' => '\d+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'frontend',
        'controller' => 'article',
        'action' => 'show',
    ));
```

I also advice you to replace the default route (only meant as an example, not to be used) with as many routes as you need.

Comment: Thanks. This is working great. And if i need too add another action like edit? How to add array of actions having action name in url to this route? Is there any option to make /article/show/id not working or maybe it is ok like that?

Comment: That array contains regexes which the parameters have to match. So regex 'add' will only match string 'add'. Regex 'add|edit' will match string 'add' or 'edit'. http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#regex

Comment: "Is there any option to make /article/show/id not working or maybe it is ok like that?" Remove the default route. Then make as many specific routes as you need to make your application work. Then /article/show/id won't work. **Catch-all routes are ugly**, avoid them.